# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (RoR)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to print the values entered into a form right below the form on the same page and I am currently receiving an error that says "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" whenever I run the server. The problem comes when I try to run the loop on the same page as the form, If I run the loop on a different path, there is no problem.

Here is the loop

```
<tbody>
        <% @orders.each do |order| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= order.drink %></td>
            <td><%= order.coffee_type %></td>
            <td><%= order.milk_amount %></td>
            <td><%= order.sugar_amount %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', order %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Order Completed', order, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my controller class for Orders

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = current_user.orders.build
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_order_path, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: That form is used in `new`? And maybe `edit`?

Comment: make sure you define `@orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC")` or `@orders = Order.all` in view's corresponding controller action

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given you're trying to render an `Order` form, I'm guessing you're in the `new` or `edit` action. And, you do something like:

```
@orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

in neither of those actions. So, naturally, `@orders` is `nil`. So, when you try to call `nil.each`, you get "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass".